# Ruby on Rails 5.2 - ArgumentError: Passing string to be evaluated in :if and :unless conditional options is not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I updated an older ruby on rails app to Rails 5.2.4 and I received the following error:

**ArgumentError: Passing string to be evaluated in :if and :unless conditional options is not supported. Pass a symbol for an instance method, or a lambda, proc or block, instead.**

The error appears for the users.rb model, on a line containing:

```
if: 'self.subscription.blank?'
```

is it ok to replace this line with:

```
if: lambda {puts 'self.subscription.blank?'}
```

I made the change and it seems to work well, I'm a rails novice, please adivse me regarding the best practice in this case. I used a lambda but I'm not sure if my code is ok or if it's the best solution.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if: lambda {puts 'self.subscription.blank?'}
```

The condition will never run here since `puts` returns `nil`, and nil is falsy.

What you actually want is:

```
if: lambda { subscription.blank? }
# or the more common short-hand
if: ->{ subscription.blank? }
```

Comment: You're right, in my tests the lambda returned nil and that's why I asked. Thank you, I will use the "common short-hand" version because it's more clean.